# Send different number of arguments to a function in a Pythonic way

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a small function which calls another function from a library I import, I have 8 similar use cases but I don't want the code to be long and repeating.

each time I send the exact same function and with the same arguments but with different number of them.

Let me show an example of what I mean:

This is my function

```
def num_pack(num, 8_bytes):
    return struct.Struct(">Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q").pack(num, num, num, num, num, num, num, num)
```

`num` is some generic counter, `8_bytes` is a variable that runs from 1 to 8.

there are 8 possible options for the function that I use, it depends on the `8_bytes` value.
The number of `Q` in the string should be equal to the number of `8_bytes` and the same goes for `num`.

The naive way to do it is :

```
    def num_pack(num, 8_bytes):
    if 8_bytes == 8:
        return struct.Struct(">Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q").pack(num, num, num, num, num, num, num, num)
    if 8_bytes == 7:
        return struct.Struct(">Q Q Q Q Q Q Q").pack(num, num, num, num, num, num, num)
    if 8_bytes == 6:
        return struct.Struct(">Q Q Q Q Q Q").pack(num, num, num, num, num, num)
    .
    .
    .
    if 8_bytes == 1:
        return struct.Struct(">Q").pack(num)
```

I know how to modify the `">Q"` string at each time by I don't know how to change the `pack` function's number of arguments.

I also know how to do this with `eval`, but this is bad practice and I don't want to use this method.

I'm sure there is some Pythonic way of doing so,
Thanks in advance !

Comment: `8_bytes` is not a valid variable name ... for your actual underlying problem, you can just use `*` unpacking

Comment: Maybe `pack(*[num]*k)` where `k = 8,7,6,...`

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function that accepts any amount of arguments using the unpack operater `*`.

Here is an example of a function that takes any amount of arguments:

```py
def my_awesome_function(*args):
   # do awesome job!
   print(args)

   # depending on len of args do something...
```

Or if you always have a one argument, but an unknown number of following arguments, you can formulate it like this:

```py
def my_awesome_function(num, *all_other_args):
   # my number
   print(num)

   # do awesome job!
   print(all_other_args)

   # depending on len of args do something...
```

Here is full explanation of how to deal with unknown number of args, and more usefull operators: https://www.scaler.com/topics/python/packing-and-unpacking-in-python/

If you are looking to do it the other way around, such that a function deeds all the items in a list as separate arguments. This could be done like this with the `*` operator as well.

```py
def foo(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

values = ['adam', 'dave', 'elon']

# a valid funciton call would be
foo(*values)

# values  -> ['adam', 'dave', 'elon']
# *values -> 'adam', 'dave', 'elon'
```

Hopefully this helps. Please leave a comment if I misunderstood.

Good Luck!